# Is there a package that show the value of constant variables? C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I would like some package that show the variable value when I put cursor on it. The behavior that I expect can be seen in the image below. The image below is in vscode, I would like some package that do the same.

[image]

Comment: Cursor or mouse pointer? I don't see the cursor (or the mouse pointer, for that matter) in your screenshot.